# ERROR 4956 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

Hi I am new to hibernate

I am getting above error while process.
This is my hibernate query

```
@Query("from Jmrrole where description=:roleName")  
public List<Jmrrole> viewUserDetails(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
```

Error:

> ERROR 4956 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper :    ORA-00923: FROM keyword
>   not found where expected

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any addition info regarding the same

Comment: I think a Query requires that you write a full sql query (e.g. @Query(" select * from Jmrrole where description =:roleName")

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a `select` statement in your query statement. Try this one:

```
@Query("select r from Jmrrole r where r.description=:roleName")  
public List<Jmrrole> viewUserDetails(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
```

Comment: This answer is already given in the comments and your sql query , as written, isn't going to work. (replace select r from Jmrrole r with select r.*   from Jmrrole r)

Comment: I have tried this one also its showing same error.I guess hibernate will act same way for all these two queries.